# Inferring linear transformations in python in order to calculate a point transformation

Tags: numpy, nonlinear-optimization, coordinate-transformation, non-linear-regression, nonlinear-functions

I have a set of points and their transformations (the points they became after the unknown transformation occurred), here they are:

```
input_coordinates = {
    'A': (5, 2), 
    'B': (2, -3), 
    'C': (-3, 6)}
final_coordinates = {
    'A': (2, -3), 
    'B': (-3, 6), 
    'C': (6, 5)}
```

I also have one single input point that I would like to infer its location in the post-transformation space:

```
x_coordinate = (5, -7)
```

And here they all are graphed out visually.

[image: setup]

So, given only a map of point-to-point conversions, and assuming a linear transformation, how do I infer the post-transformation point? How do I know where to place X on the right graph?

Are there already any libraries that will do this?

With John Hughes help I've started a function that should return the correct result for linear transformations but I can't figure out how to finish the function.

Here's the starter code for the Linear Transformation solution:

```
def extrapolate(domain_coordinates, result_coordinates, point):
    '''
    given a set of input coordinates and their resulting
    coordinates post-transformation, and given an additional 
    input coordinate return the location (coordinate) in the
    post-transformation space that corresponds to the most
    logical linear transformation of that space for that
    additional point. "extrapolate where this point ends up"
    '''
    import numpy as np

    # Add the number 1 to the coordinates for each point
    domain = [(x, y, 1) for x, y in domain_coordinates]

    # Do the same for the "target" coordinates too
    result = [(x, y, 1) for x, y in result_coordinates]

    # Put these coordinates, arranged vertically, into a 3×3 matrix
    domain = np.array(domain).T
    result = np.array(result).T

    # D^−1 is the "matrix inverse"
    inverse = np.linalg.inv(domain)

    # Let M=RD^−1
    matrix = result * inverse         # why do I need M?...

    # Do the same for the extrapolation point
    xpoint = [(x, y, 1) for x, y in [point]]
    xpoint = np.array(xpoint).T

    # extrapolate ???
    extrapolated_point = matrix * xpoint    # this isn't right...

    # testing
    print(domain * np.array([[1],[0],[0]]).T)
    print(domain * np.array([[1],[0],[0]]).T * matrix)

    return extrapolated_point


extrapolate(
    domain_coordinates=[(5, 2), (2, -3), (-3, 6)],
    result_coordinates=[(2, -3), (-3, 6), (6, 5)],
    point=(5, -7))
```

This code is not working right, it prints...

```
[[5 0 0]
 [2 0 0]
 [1 0 0]]
[[ 1.73076923  0. -0.]
 [-0.57692308 -0.  0.]
 [-0.34615385  0.  0.]]
```

whereas I would expect it to print...

```
[[5 0 0]
 [2 0 0]
 [1 0 0]]
[[ 2  0.  0.]
 [-3  0.  0.]
 [-1  0.  0.]]
```

Can you show me where I've gone wrong?

Thanks so much for your help!